Preflight request is succeeds, but GET request fails with CORS error status code 200 OK
For context I've set up an API gateway and integrated a lambda.
The preflight request is returning 204 alongside Access-Control-* headers. However, the GET request has a CORS error but a status code of 200 OK
I saw a similar stack overflow question but no help.
What am I doing wrong?
Here are some screenshots:




The GET request lacks the Access-Control-* headers, that's why the browser reports the CORS error.

Fixed. Turns out I had to return the same Access-Control-* from the lambda as well.
